# Finding the index where a value in a certain row begins with a specific string - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, attributeerror

I have such a pandas dataframe:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
nullnull 0 1
7 8 9
```

I now want to find out the index of the row where the `nullnull` is. To use this index for slicing in order to get only the rows before this index.

I tried something like this:

```
row = df.ix[df['A'].startswith("nullnull")].index.tolist()
```

And got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

How could I do this using `startswith` or maybe using another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `loc` or `.iloc`

```
row = df.loc[df['A'].str.startswith("nullnull")].index.tolist()
row
Out[549]: [2]
```